# How does two way mutual authentication works while accessing third party server through Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, curl

I am trying to access third service using POST request and Spring Rest Template. When I try it using Curl Command, I am getting perfect Response.

```
curl -k --data @body.json -v --cert tomcat -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' https://220.227.71.46:9444/eko/initiateIMPSFundTransfer
```

Here tomcat is the nickname of my server certificate.
My problem arises when I m trying to do same with Java.
First I tried to ignore the SSL authentication. I am skipping the code for that will POST if someone requires. But when I call the POST request I receive a error response that Remote Host Connect Closed.When I try to register my my key store and set the SSL context with it with the below code. I get the error.     org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://220.227.71.46:9444/eko/initiateIMPSFundTransfer": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

```
    InputStream keyStoreInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("test.webservices.eko.co.in.jks");
    log.info("keyStoreInputStream " + keyStoreInputStream);
    if (keyStoreInputStream == null) {
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "Could not find file named 'test.webservices.eko.co.in.jks' in the CLASSPATH");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    KeyStore trustStore = null;
    try {
        trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        trustStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException |
            IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            keyStoreInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My doubt is that I am registering the keystore of my server, my java Keystore also have this .jks where I am running this application. Instead of this do I need to register the certificate of the server which I am accessing. What is the meaning of the above error and how can I solve it.

I am new to SSL validations, so please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the SSL certificate of the remote server to the keystore your Java code is using when it attempts to make the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already added the certificate in the keystore but still it is giving me the same problem.

Comment: Now I am getting error                                                                             Remote host closed connection during handshake; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake